# Dynamic methods in PHP

Tags: php, class, object, dynamic, methods

I found a way to do the following call using dynamic methods in PHP (input and img are just example, this could create anything):

```
$Form->insert->input(array('type' => 'text', 'name' => 'firstName', 'maxlength' => '100', 'value' => 'First name'))
$Form->insert->img(array('id' => 'banner', 'src' => '/images/banner.svg'))
```

This trick uses two object (Form and FormInsert). And Form insert uses the _call method which means I could create any HTML object with this method.

While this works well, I was wondering if there is a way to use the following, nicer syntax instead?:

```
$Form->insert->input->type('text')->name('firstName')->maxlength('100')->value('First name')
$Form->insert->img->id('banner')->src('/images/banner.svg')
```

The idea would be to create not just inputs but any sort of HTML element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask is common practice in jQuery and you surely can do it in PHP, all you need to do is to return the object every time:

```
class FormInsert
{
    ...

    public function __call( $method, $args )
    {
        // do the cool stuff 

        return $this;
    }
    ...
}
```

This way you'd be coming back to the `FomrInput` object to add details about the tag you are building.

---

The idea sounds interesting. I see a few problems there though if you limit yourself to just two classes. It would seem to me that the `FormInsert` class would be huge and full of controls to deal with particular cases and "HTML-tag syntax".

If I think of ways to solve those problems, I end up with a class per HTML tag and no need for the magic method `__call()`... then again, I haven't gone that deep into the problem.

Comment: Looking great! Can you provide a full example? For some reasons I'm trying to implement this and I'm getting some odd errors...

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: FormInsert::$input in C:\htdocs\index.php on line 48

Fatal error: Call to a member function type() on a non-object in C:\htdocs\index.php on line 48

Comment: I found the problem, it looks like for this specific case I might need 3 classes unless I want to use $Form->insert->img()->id('banner')->src('/images/banner.svg') rather than $Form->insert->img->id('banner')->src('/images/banner.svg') - Still working on the code but I should figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to others but I managed to get the following 3 classes which can help semantically create HTML objects in PHP while tracking some information that can be reused in PHP (such as IDs within an object or 'names' within a form). The following object is for a form but could be used for a 'body' object as well.

```
class ElementAttribute {

    protected $parent; // Parent class object

    function __construct(&$parent, $element) {
        $this->parent = &$parent;

        $this->rootElement = &$this->parent;
        if (@is_object($this->rootElement->parent)) {
            $this->rootElement = &$this->rootElement->parent; // Set root element
        }
        $this->rootClassName = strtolower(get_class($this->rootElement)); // Set root class name object
        $this->element = $element; // Define current HTML element
        $this->s = '<'.$this->element; // Initialize HTML string
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {

        $method = strtolower($method); // User lowercase by convention for HTML5

        if (isset($args[0])) {
            // Add available attributes to root element when created
            if ($this->element == $this->rootClassName) {
                if (@property_exists($this->rootElement, $method)) {
                    $this->rootElement->$method = $args[0];
                }
            }
            // Add available attribute arrays to root element when created
            $a = $method.'s';
            if (@property_exists($this->rootElement, $a)) {
                array_push($this->rootElement->$a, $args[0]);
            }
            $this->s .= ' '.$method.'="'.$args[0].'"';
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        $s = $this->s.'>';
        $m = $this->rootElement->lastUsedMethod;
        unset($this->rootElement->$m); // Unset HTML object from root object so that a new object can replace it
        return $s;
    }
}

class HtmlElement {

    protected $parent; // Parent class object

    function __construct(&$parent) {
        $this->parent = &$parent;
    }

    function __get($name) {
        if (!@is_object($this->$name)) {
            $this->$name = new ElementAttribute($this, $name);
        }
        return $this->$name;
    }

}

class Form {

    public $id; // Form Id
    public $name = ''; // Form Name
    public $ids = array(); // List of object Ids within the form
    public $names = array(); // List of object Names within the form
    public $lastUsedMethod; // Track last used dynamic method

    function __get($name) {
        if ($name == 'open') { // Open current HTML element tag
            $this->$name = new ElementAttribute($this, get_class($this));
        } else if ($name == 'insert') { // Insert new HTML element
            $this->$name = new HtmlElement($this);
        }
        $this->lastUsedMethod = $name;
        return $this->$name;
    }

}
```

Some examples on how to use it:

```
$Form = new Form();

echo $Form->open->id('signup')->method('post')->autocomplete('off')->autocorrect('off')->action('/toto');

var_dump($Form);

echo $Form->insert->input->type('text')->name('firstName')->maxlength('100')->value('First name');

var_dump($Form);

echo $Form->insert->input->type('text')->name('lastName')->maxlength('100')->value('Last name');

var_dump($Form);
```